# How to log nested objects with elastic (ELK) stack

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying to log a JSON value with nested properties to a logzio ELK stack via NodeJS

The code is:

```
var logger = require('logzio-nodejs').createLogger({
  token: config.LOGZIO_API_KEY
});


// sending text
logger.log('This is a log message');

// sending an object
var obj = {
  message: 'Some log message',
  param1: 'val1',
  param2: 'val2'
};

logger.log(obj);
```

This works fine, but if I want to log nested data such as:

```
// sending an object
var obj = {
  message: 'Some log message',
  param1: {
    a : 'b',
    c : 'd'
  },
  param2: 'val2'
};
```

This returns an error:

```
{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [param1]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown property [a]"}}
```

What can I adjust that will allow me to log this nested object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you've logged `param1` as a string, ES created a field of type string.

Thereafter, you tried to log `param1` as an object and that was conflicting with the the string type.

However, you can definitely log a nested object but you have to give it another name that a field that already exists, say `param3`, that should work:

```
// sending an object
var obj = {
  message: 'Some log message',
  param3: {
    a : 'b',
    c : 'd'
  },
  param2: 'val2'
};
```

Comment: Awesome. If I delete all those indexes where `param1` is a string, will it fix this issue for me? (PS: thx for the answer!)

Comment: Yes, it should.